# How to make To-address read-only when creating mail message with Outlook automation?

Tags: c#, outlook, automation

Is it possible to set the To textbox to be read-only when you create and display a mail message in outlook with Office automation? We use the following code to create the message:

```
   Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)objOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
   // setting properties...
   mail.Display(modal);
```

Comment: Why do you need a full blown outlook? You can use a simple Form with a Rich Edit Text and from there you can control everything.

Comment: Sure, but this is how the application works today and the users want all the features that outlook gives them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way that I know of, but one way is to use P/Invoke and native APIs to set the state of the textbox to read-only. It involves getting a handle to the textbox, which is the tricky part. If you poke around with Spy++, you may get insight into the window's hierarchy and how to get it's handle.